# How to write custom validation on django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

How to write custom validations on drf. I have validate function on serializer. Can someone help whats wrong with my code?
my views:

```
class MyCustomView(ListCreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = MyCustomSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

my serializer:

```
class MyCustomView(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=64)
    address = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=64)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if not attrs.get('name'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Name field is required.')
```

when i request with blank name and address it shows default drf error. How to override this function?

Comment: You must return `attrs` after validation is performed in `validate()` method

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to return attrs after validation.

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    if not attrs.get('name'):
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Name field is required.')
    return attrs
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **required=True** from both of your fields.

but it's better you don't bother your backend with empty data and have your frontend handle it.